# How many different 6-digit numbers can be made by using each of the following six digits: 2,5,5,9,9,9 exactly once?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I am able to solve if the digits are different by using the solution 6x5x4x3x2x1=720 but with the repeated numbers, I am not sure how to apply this method.

Comment: How many ways are there to place the $9's$?  After they are placed, how many ways are there to place the $5's$?

Answer (score 1):

You need to divide by $3!$ for the nine's and by $2!$ for the fives, giving $60$.

Comment: shouldn't it be 120 then?

Comment: @JacquelineKuek $\frac{6!}{2!\cdot 3!}=\frac{720}{2\cdot 6}=60$

Comment: Ok i think i understand now